# заголовок $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']

Tags: php

Почему этот заголовок на айфоне не показывает поддержку webp ? Но картинки webp загружаются. Месяц назад такой проблемы не было.

text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7  это на компьютере

text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 на айфоне

Comment: Версия браузера на айфоне какая? Месяц назад была такая же?

Comment: Не обновлял раньше (обновил после обнаружения ошибки. ничего не изменилось. сейчас стоит 23.7.2.670). Раньше сафари/яндекс показывали в заголовке webp